# Python: Read text file with column headers in rows into new CSV/Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a text file that i want to output into a new .csv file.  The column headings are in-line to the data and I cannot figure out how to process the file.  I am a python newbie.

The input file format is:
{"column 1 name":"column 1 value", "column 2 name":"column 2 value", "column 3 name":"column 3 value", "column 4 name":"column 4 value", "column 5 name":"column 5 value"}

The output file format i want is:
column headers in line 1
comma separated values in lines 2 and beyond

There are also times where a value may be blank so i need to account for that so the values don't shift to the wrong column header.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it's a text file and not a json file? From your example it looks like you could use `json.load()` from the [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: Thanks!  I am not sure.  I am provided the files in .txt formal  Is there a way to quickly test that?

Comment: Yes. `import json <start a new line> with open ('the_file_name.txt', 'r') as infile: <press enter and then indent this next line with 4 spaces> data = json.load(infile)` obviously with the instructions between `<>` removed.

Comment: I did that and received an error   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 244 column 1 (char 259 - 66680)

Comment: Ok thanks for testing that. In that case, I'm confused about what format your data is in... unless I'm mistaken, the json parser made it to line 244 before it hit some data it didn't like. It's not clear to me how to read this file.

Comment: What happens if you change `data = json.load(infile)` to `data = infile.readlines()` and what do you get from `print(len(data))`?

Comment: It returns 2719

Answer (score 0):

Your input file format isn't 100% clear. It looks like it is JSON and I am assuming that there is one JSON per line. I'd further assume that there are no line breaks between single entry.

Your question may best be split into two parts.

## 1. Reading Input File - JSON lines

Assumed data `test.jl` (jl for JSON lines):

```
{"header1": "value1.1", "header2": "value1.2"}
{"header1": "value2.1", "header2": "value2.2"}
```

Then you could read that file line by line and JSON parse each line:

```
import json

with open('test.jl') as input_f:
  data = [json.loads(line) for line in input_f]

print(data)
```

`data` here will be a list of dict's, output:

```
[{'header2': 'value1.2', 'header1': 'value1.1'}, {'header2': 'value2.2', 'header1': 'value2.1'}]
```

## 2. Writing Output File from a list of dict's

### 2a. Determining the list of fields

Unless you already have a fixed list of fields, you may need to determine that list first.

You could go through every dict, get its keys and build a unique list of it, like so:

```
from functools import reduce

all_keys = sorted(reduce(lambda acc, item: acc | set(item.keys()), data, set()))

print(all_keys)
```

Here we start with an empty `set()` (to the right), which will be the first `acc` and every dict in `data` will become `item`. We are adding (using the `|` operator) the `keys()` to `acc` and the return value will become next round's `acc` (or the final return value). Since we are using sets, there won't be duplicates. The `sorted` just gives it a final touch but is optional.

Output:

```
['header1', 'header2']
```

### 2b. Writing the CSV

Well, there is DictWriter which seems to fit the bill.

```
from csv import DictWriter

with open('test.csv', 'w') as csv_f:
  csv_writer = DictWriter(csv_f, fieldnames=all_keys)
  csv_writer.writeheader()
  csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

Output in test.csv:

```
header1,header2
value1.1,value1.2
value2.1,value2.2
```

Comment: This appears to have worked.  I am validating the data from the json and the csv file to see if it matches.  One thing I noticed is that the columns (keys) are not in the orginal order of the JSON file.  Is there a way to preserve that and have the CSV output the same.  I opened it in excel and it requires me to re-order the data.  Hope to make this fully automated.  Thanks for the great help!

Comment: @DVictor the JSON is parsed to a dict, I don't think you can rely on the order of the keys in there. You could manually extract the order from the text as it appears but as you say not all of the items contain all of the keys. And also usually on the JSON generating side the order is not deterministic. If you want a specific order I'd just pass that in or make it configurable.